# Get headlines from any webpage

Tags: jquery

How to get headlines titles from the webpage? For example If user visit **Yahoo** webpage I need to get all title listed in **Yahoo** home page? I am trying to use **JQuery** find method.

I am trying like...

```
$("div").find("h1")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: wats d purpose and be more specific and paste details code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("head title")[0];
```

OR

```
document.title
```